# I want to get H[1] without using H

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
H = ['value1' , 'value2']
Li = ['value3' , 'value4']
Be = ['value5' , 'value6']
C = ['value7' , 'value8']

element = input('Enter Your Choice:')
#user types H
```

i want to get value2 without using H
i want to get it via element
is it possible ?

Comment: I'd recommend using dictionaries. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Answer (score 2):

This kind of data should always be stored in a dictionary, not in parallel variables:

```
elements = {
  'H': ['value1' , 'value2'],
  'Li': ['value3' , 'value4'],
  'Be': ['value5' , 'value6'],
  'C': ['value7' , 'value8']
]

element = input('Enter Your Choice:')
print(elements[element][1])
```